# Turning a list with varying vector lengths into a dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm trying to convert a named list of vectors with varying lengths into a dataframe so that I can plot it later. Right now, I have a list that looks like this:

```
list <- list(a=c("foo"), b=c("foo","foo"), c=c("foo", "foo", "bar"))
```

What I'd like is a dataframe that looks like this:

```
letters=c("a","b","b","c","c","c") 
text=c("foo","foo","foo","foo", "foo", "bar")
df <- data.frame(letters,text)
```

I realize this is probably pretty simple, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Be carefully with 'letters', is a R function...

Comment: ... and `list` is another function. It is not considered good practise to create object names with those reserve words

Comment: Sorry, I know. They aren't that way in my actual data, just creating easy object names for purposes of the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `stack` or `melt`

```
stack(list)
```

Or

```
library(reshape2)
melt(list)
```

Comment: That's the one! Thank you @akrun!